# NullPointerException on ENTER-key press in JavaFX Application Thread

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx, javafx-8

I currently have the following situation:

I want to make my application listen to user input. First, I did this with an invisible TextField, but this screwed up my design and I thought it was not sophisticated enough. So, I am now trying to make a onKeyPressed EventHandler on my upper FlowPane, like this:

```
public String input = "";
@FXML public void listenToInput(KeyEvent key) {

    if (key.getCode() != KeyCode.ENTER) {

        if (key.getCode().isDigitKey() || key.getCode().isLetterKey()) {
            String newChar = key.getText();
            input = input.concat(newChar);
        }

    }
    else {
        this.addScanToList(input);
        input = "";
    }

}
```

This is working for just plain text and digits. But as soon as I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableViewBehaviorBase.activate(TableViewBehaviorBase.java:915)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableViewBehaviorBase.callAction(TableViewBehaviorBase.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableViewBehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(TableViewBehaviorBase.java:208)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$75(BehaviorBase.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$$Lambda$146/1103773754.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3926)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3872)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2001)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2463)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$346(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$208/996795822.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:406)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:540)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:950)
```

Where I already thought of:

- The upper FlowPane has no focus, but then I gave it focus, but no result.
- The enter key does not get recognized, which could be true, because the 'else' of my listenToInput never gets entered.

**EDIT 1:**

- The FlowPane does not have a 'setOnAction', so it does not know how to handle the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> press.

Does anyone know what triggers this error?

**Edit 2:**

I changed onKeyPressed to onKeyReleased, and then my code runs properly, but I still get the error. Maybe it helps to know that.

**Edit 3:**

I tried to add the scan to the list with <kbd>ALT</kbd> instead of <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and this works perfectly, so it has something to do with the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for several days, I was able to fix this. As I already mentioned in Edit 3, it had something to do with the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. When it was pressed, it looked like the FXML file was searching for an element which could consume an action. Somehow, the first thing it found was a TableView. I tried this code to make it non-focusable:

```
tableview.setFocusTraversable(false)
```

And it works. Can anyone explain what JavaFX wants to do with the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key? I had my focus on the FlowPane, so it should send the action to the appropriate listener. If it has something to do with a Event Handler that has to be overridden, please let me know.

Comment: Probably it's because the TableView is editable, so it's looking for the next cell to edit on Enter press

Answer (score 0):

That's how I usually add a keyEvent Handler to listen to key events.

```
FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
pane.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
        if (key.getCode() != KeyCode.ENTER) {

            if (key.getCode().isDigitKey() || key.getCode().isLetterKey()) {
                String newChar = key.getText();
                input = input.concat(newChar);
            }

        }
        else {
            this.addScanToList(input);
            input = "";
        }

    }
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have set the action in the FXML file, so isn't that basically the same as what you are suggesting?